# contenteditable for inline editing with ckEditor

Tags: php, html, ckeditor

I'm creating an inline CMS using ckeditor. The idea is:

- Client logs into admin area
- Login beings a session
- Client is directed to pages on their website where they can edit predefined regions

The regions are specified with the contenteditable attribute:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
  safsdfdfsdfdfsdfsdfds
</div>
```

Since a session is created when the client logs in, I've written some PHP that knows to enable ckEditor and all the CMS functionality if the client is logged in.

The issue I have, is when not logged in, `contenteditable="true"` on divs still allows you to edit them without a WYSIWYG as the default behaviour for the browser. Obviously this is no good. How do I stop users being able to edit the page?

Comment: dont even display the div's if the visitor is not logged in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could setup the divs like that:

```
<div data-contenteditable="true">
```

And have a JavaScript (if in admin mode) go over all divs (document.getElementsByTagName("div")) and if they have data-contenteditable set the real contenteditable.

Otherwise let the server only include contenteditable if in admin mode

Comment: Thanks, yeh I don't know why I didn't think of doing it with jQuery replace

Answer (score 0):

In PHP:

Create first a function that returns true if the user is logged in, then, for each editable region (in your views):

```
<div<?php if (your_login_check_function()) echo ' contenteditable="true"'; ?>>Lorem ipsum</div>
```

It's a bit tedious but it should work.

Or in jQuery (as proposed by [Moritz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18990822/contenteditable-for-inline-editing-with-ckeditor#answer-18990902)):

Add a *data-contenteditable="true"* to your editable nodes, then add a script to the end of the page when the user is logged in:

```
<script>$('[data-contenteditable]').attr('contenteditable', true);</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I should have mentioned, your PHP method is what I'm already doing. Problem is, it's not all that neat and I need to make the CMS super easy for others to install, so wanted to make it as simple as adding a class to each div. So I'll do it the jQuery way. Thanks